# Spring Security Java config does not intercept request accessing JSP available only for authenticated sources

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am making a Spring MVC web application. I have a login page and a dashboard page. Anyone attempting to access the dashboard JSP must be logged in:

Here's my Spring Security config:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
@Import({SpringConfiguration.class})
public class SecurityContext extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;  

    // authorizeRequests() -> use-expresions = "true"
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/createaccount","/error", "/register", "/login", "/newaccount", "/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**", "/*", "/").authenticated()  
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
            .csrf();

        // Upon starting the application, it prints the asdfasdf so I know the SecurityContext is loaded
        System.out.println("asdfasdf");
    }


    // Equivalent of jdbc-user-service in XML
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, enabled FROM Users WHERE username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, authority FROM authorities where username=?");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have some endpoints which I permit anyone to access such as `/login`, `/register`, but all other URLs require that they be authenticated. When I start the application, if I try go to the dashboard page, I can access it just fine without needing to login which is not what I want.

My issue is that I want people attempting to reach the dashboard to be sent to the login page if they are not logged in/authenticated.

I'm trying to avoid using XML entirely and only use Java to configure my application, would anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I am almost certain it's something wrong with with my SecurityContext.

I might as well include the context XML too of which I'm trying to convert to Java config style

```xml
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:jdbc-user-service
                data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select username, password, enabled from Users where username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select username, authority from Authority where username =?  " />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:http use-expressions="true">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/newaccount"
            access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/accountcreated"
            access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createaccount"
            access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/error"
            access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**"
            access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login"
            access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/setemote"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />


    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
    <security:csrf />

</security:http>
```

Comment: I'm grateful for your explanation, upvoted it and it did help but I haven't come to a conclusive solution yet since it was helped with a part of what I've done wrong. Still tinkering at it, I was going to comment at the end if I got either stuck or fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day.

You have to be sure that you have `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer`, looking like that:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SecurityContext.class);
    }
}
```

Where `SecurityContext` - is your class extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

If you already have it then the problem might be in the lack of roles.

To have roles you might want to implement the config a bit differently, something like that:

```
    .antMatchers("/restricted_area/*")
        .access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll();
```

For working with roles and authentication you can extend `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService` having a separate class that would work along with the Spring' authorization/authentication machinery checking the credentials.

As you see I also have authenticationSuccessHandler here. This is actually extended

```
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler
```

What it does is redirecting to specific pages depending on the role: e.g. regular user to user' dashboard, admin to admin' dashboard.
Not sure if this is relevant to your question though, but the implementation is something like that:

```
@Component("customHandler")
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationHandler.class);

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        String username = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
        userService.updateLastLoginTimeByName(username);
        handle(request, response, authentication);
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }

    protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException {
        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication);

        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            logger.debug("Response has already been committed. Unable to redirect to " + targetUrl);
            return;
        }

        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }

    /**
     * Builds the target URL according to the logic defined in the main class
     * Javadoc.
     */
    protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {
        boolean isAdmin = false;
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
        for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
             if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
                isAdmin = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isAdmin) {
            return "/restricted_area/";
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

    protected void clearAuthenticationAttributes(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session == null) {
            return;
        }
        session.removeAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
    }

    public void setRedirectStrategy(RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy) {
        this.redirectStrategy = redirectStrategy;
    }

    protected RedirectStrategy getRedirectStrategy() {
        return redirectStrategy;
    }
}
```

Comment: To add to this: I was also missing the annotation @EnableWebSecurity.

There was a post that was deleted telling me to remove it, I read it took heed of it before it was taken down but it didn't seem to affect my application so I didn't reverse the changes.

Not sure if relevant, but in my WebApplicationInitializer class (web.xml in Java) - I also found that I should remove securityFilters since they're auto-created.

I've been jumping thread after thread trying to convert the XML to Java so I guess that's how I missed what was suggested in this answer. Thanks for the help c: